# Python selenium - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86 using ChromeDriver and Chrome with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When running my code I get this error:

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86
```

Current browser version is 88.0.4324.104 with binary path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Is it possible that my version is too big?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error message...

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86 Current browser version is 88.0.4324.104 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that you are using [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) **v86.x** where as your *Chrome Browser* version is **v88.0.4324.104**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=86.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=86.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/86.0.4240.22/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 86**

- You are using *chrome=88.0.4324.104*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 88**

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=86.0* and the *ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v88.0.4324.96](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/88.0.4324.96/notes.txt) level.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

The version you are using is outdated, type "version://chrome" into your browser and see what exact version you have. Then go to the [chromedriver download](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)  and download the one for your version.

As your error says your version is "88.0.4324.104" so [download this one](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can download chrome driver version 86 from this link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=86.0.4240.22/